# I need to dynamically introduce values from asp.net (vb) code behind to a payment gateway .aspx?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The above header refers.

Please, find below the aspx file in question- I just need a working .vb to interact with it. Thanks in advance.

This is a typical line:

`<input type="hidden" name="ce_merchantid" value="<%=cemertid %>" />`

Comment: Can you please explain the problem that you are trying to resolve a bit more?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network.
You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if your question is clearer, shows some of the research you’ve done, what you’ve tried, what errors you got, etc. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I am attempting to integrate a payment gateway with my asp.net site. I need to be able to pass dynamic values from the code behind to the markup file (.aspx).

Comment: cemertid is defined as string in the markup file as follows:

Comment: <script runat="server">
    Dim cemertid As String = "1106" </script>

Comment: So, how do I define or reference cemertid in the code behind (.vb) file and pass dynamic to the markup at run time?

Answer (score 1):

A property should be all you need in the code behind with your hidden input above. Just set _cemertid somwhere in your code.

```
  Private _cemertid As String = "1234"

  Public ReadOnly Property cemertid As String
      Get
          Return _cemertid 
      End Get
  End Property
```

Comment: I have done this so I could assign a dynamic value in the page load procedure:   Private _cemertid As String = "1234"

  Public WriteOnly Property cemertid As String
      Get
          Return _cemertid 
      End Get
  End Property. But the challenge is that the value I assigned to the variable in page load (in the code behind) is not being passed to the onload form when it is being rendered. So, what is left to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Piecing together your question with the comments that you have made, it sounds as though you are already pulling the necessary value into a variable in `PageLoad` sub.

```
Asp.NET:
<asp:HiddenField ID="ce_merchantid" runat="server" />
```

Instead of the your `<input>` attempt to use this asp HiddenField control and in the page load routine, assign the value to this hidden field.

```
VB.NET:
ce_merchantid.Value = "1234"
```

Comment: Hi.

I don't think this would work because the payment gateway specifically requires a name component when passing values to it. Besides ce_merchantid is already defined as string within <script runat="server"> ... </script> as string and assigned a default value, which I want to change in the .vb file before the asp.net onload event is fired. Thanks.